# Trying some subquery in select with diff of sum - Doctrine 2.6.4

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I try to do some query in symfony and Doctrine 2.6.4.

My problem is, i tried to do some subquery in my select. In Mysql it's look like:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE((SELECT 
                SUM(bill.amount)
            FROM
                bill
            WHERE
                bill.bill__client_id = cl.id),
        0) AS `total_to_pay`,
COALESCE((SELECT 
                SUM(payement.price + payement.taxes)
            FROM
                payement
            WHERE
                payement.payement__client_id = cl.id),
        0) AS `total_already_pay`,
COALESCE((SELECT 
                SUM(bill.amount)
            FROM
                bill
            WHERE
                bill.bill__client_id = cl.id),
        0) - COALESCE((SELECT 
                SUM(payement.price + payement.taxes)
            FROM
                payement
            WHERE
                payement.payement__client_id = cl.id),
        0) AS `total_to_pay_today`
FROM
client AS cl
```

WHERE
cl.id = x;

In doctrine, i tried this:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('cl')
                ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(bi.amount) FROM App\Entity\Bill bi WHERE bi.billClient = cl.id) AS total_to_pay')
                ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(pa.amount) FROM App\Entity\Payments pa WHERE pa.payementClient = cl.id) AS total_already_pay')
                ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(bii.amount) FROM App\Entity\Bill bii WHERE bii.billClient = cl.id)-(SELECT SUM(paa.price + paa.taxes) FROM App\Entity\Payments paa WHERE pa.payementClient = cl.id) as total_to_pay_today')
                ->where('cl.id = :client_id')
                ->setParameter('client_id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSQL();
```

It's return this error:

```
Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '-'
```

Ty for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use Joins instead of subselects:

```
        ->addSelect('SUM(bi.amount) as total_to_pay')
        ->addSelect('SUM(pa.amount) as total_already_pay')
        ->addSelect('SUM(bi.amount) - SUM(pa.price + pa.taxes) as total_to_pay_today')
        ->where('cl.id = :client_id')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Bill', 'bi', 'WITH', 'bi.billClient = cl.id')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Payments', 'pa', 'WITH', 'pa.payementClient = cl.id')
        ->groupBy('cl.id')
```

The problem is not in doctrine - it is in Your subquery. You can not add/substract etc result of different queries, You can check it by trying to get result of:
`(SELECT 3 FROM users WHERE id = 1) - (SELECT 2 FROM users WHERE id = 1);`
very similar error:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '- (SELECT 2 FROM users WHERE id = 1)' at line 1
```